# Trying to get lo-fi drums such as these ones and an overall effect that sounds lo-fi.

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

Does anybody know the effects that were used on the hats and the snares to achieve that crispy sound? I know the overall effect on the song is achieved by using heavy compression.

Comment: I can't see your link as is. I can't tell if it's just my browser or not, but I had to click "edit" and copy it from the source of the post. The track in question is: https://soundcloud.com/escents/days

Comment: That is weird because I seem to be getting the embedded soundcloud player whenever I open this question. Is this why this question got downvoted?

Comment: Are you live micing for recording or are you doing post/samples?

Comment: I am doing it through both post and samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure for things like this.

I hear quite a bit of **distortion** on both the hats and the share, enough that I'd say that's the major component of the "crisp" sound. This gives them a fair bit of high-frequency energy, which makes them stand out since there don't seem to be many other sounds in that register.

They're also very "choppy" - they have fast onsets and decays. The hihat ducks when the kick plays (probably through sidechain compression) and almost nothing else (besides a hat) plays when the snare does.

There is fairly little reverb or "space" effect on either of them, so they sound upfront in the mix. It's also worth mentioning that, at least on the headphones I'm listening on, they're simply louder than a lot of other parts, which probably helps.

Again, it's hard to say for sure but that's what it sounds like to me!

Comment: Very good points that been made here. THE fast onsets and decays part is giving a whole new feel to the track.

Comment: above explanation seemed the best to me as well.  Try fab filters saturn as there are many different types of distortion on there and gives you the ability to have it dialed to a particular band.  In this case I would say the higher frequencies

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like bit reduction to around 8 bits with some low-pass filtering and a small room reverb.

Comment: what elements are you refering to? I reckon that is definitely the case with the hats and the snares.

Comment: Yes, the hats and the snares. The kick is modulated by a ducking effect - either heavy side-chained compression (as you indicated) or a side-chained gate with a release envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a blend of an 8bit down sample along side a "telephone" stlye EQ (most daw eqs come with a preset. Slap it on and change to hpf and lpf till it sounds similar (maybe round 3k for the lpf)